# Automatic indexing of jcenter in mvnrepository.com?

Tags: maven, jcenter

I recently added a new open source project to the JCenter repository through a bintray account. FYI, it's located [here](https://github.com/nicolas-van/eventemitter). I can confirm it is installable with this gradle file:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'io.github.nicolas-van:eventemitter:0.0.6'
}
```

Now I would like this project to display on https://mvnrepository.com/ , because it's kind of the reference to search for Java libraries (well... the only one that works accross multiple maven repositories as far as I know). I'm assuming that the indexing is automatic and performed on cron (mostly because I can't find **any** form of documentation regarding that website, so I have to guess). Still, after two days it doesn't display.

Now for my questions:

- Is the indexing on https://mvnrepository.com/ fully automatic or is there some obscure process to perform in order to see your project on it ?
- If it's automatic what's the mean time before indexing new projects ? Days, weeks ? Also, what if a project is already indexed and you publish a new version ? Still many days to wait in order to just see the new version ?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Searching in Central can be done via:  https://search.maven.org/  All the other questions can only being answered by the maintainer(s) of mvnrepository ...

Comment: I never said I was asking one of the maintainers of the Maven Central repository. I'm just asking to whoever has sufficient knowledge about mvnrepository.com .

Comment: I have not claimed that you asked the maintainers of Maven Central. It was only a hint for searching ...